# Why this code isn't running successfully?

Tags: python

Here is the simple code but I can't run!
My code is:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("My name is "+name+". "+"My name length is " + len(str(name)))
```

and Output is:

```
What is your name? Ali
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\iamAl\Desktop\Python\main.py", line 2, in <module> 
    print("My name is "+name+". "+"My name length is " + len(str(name)))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: `len()` will always return an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print a number you should use `,` insted of  `+`, in this case len() returns an int so if you want to print the string length  you should first convert it to a string.

I suggest using `.format` to print various type of data:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("My name is {}. My name length is: {}".format(name,len(str(name))))
```

Comment: I'd suggest using an f-string and to drop the superfluous call to `str` (`name` is already a string): `print(f'My name is {name}. My name length is: {len(name)}')`

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the int returned from `len` to an `str`, not cast `str` to `str` and then use `len`

```
print("My name is " + name + ". " + "My name length is " + str(len(name)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Python is dynamic, but strongly typed. It won't let you add a string to an integer directly. You need to convert the types so they're compatible (meaning there has to be an [addition operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__add__) that can handle adding them).

Possible solutions are:

1. Cast one type to the other: `str(len(name))`
2. Use a string interpolation method such as [fstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/): `f"My name is {name}. My name length is {len(name)}"`

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have pointed out, `len` returns an `int`, and you can't concatenate a `str` and an `int` with `+`.

However, you shouldn't be using `+` like this, as each `+` has to make a copy of its arguments. Use one of the string-formatting options instead, all of which will attempt to convert a non-`str` value to a `str` value for you, as well as creating only *one* string (for the result) in the process, not a series of temporary strings. For example,

```
print(f"My name is {name}. My name length is {len(name)}")
```